# rabbitmq ldap authorization for groups with inconsistent user DNs

Tags: ldap, rabbitmq, pattern-matching

I'm trying to set up rabbitmq authorization against LDAP (Microsoft Active Directory) using the `in_group` or `in_group_nested` queries.  However, since our `OU` structure is inconsistent across our users, which results in a variety of `DN` patterns, I had to rely on a `user_dn_pattern` that simply passes the `"domain\account"` when binding, which works great from an authentication perspective with Microsoft Active Directory.  However, when it comes to the `in_group`/`in_group_nested` queries, it doesn't match because the members property is a list of actual `DN`s, and logs show that it's trying to find `"domain\account"` in the member list.

Since the LDAP plugin demands a single pattern to construct `DN`s from the supplied username, am I simply out of luck to use group level LDAPauthorization in RabbitMQ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include examples for the DNs you want to match. Please also include the patterns you have tried. Maybeit is possible to define a pattern that matches all your cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible even considering DN inconsistencies, the issue here seems to reside in the way usernames are translated into DNs during the authentication.

Instead of relying on a dn pattern, try via an LDAP lookup.

The key is to set `dn_lookup_bind` to do the lookup *before* the user authentication. This way, the LDAP plugin will bind with these credentials first to do the lookup, then bind with the matching entry's DN to do the user login :

```
auth_ldap.dn_lookup_attribute = userPrincipalName     # or sAMAccountName
auth_ldap.dn_lookup_base = dc=example,dc=com          # restrict to user ou if any
auth_ldap.dn_lookup_bind = {managerDN, Password}      # AD manager account

# auth_ldap.user_dn_pattern should be left unset to be sure the lookup actually searches 
# for a match in dn_lookup_attribute and not for a built-up dn.
```

I mentioned credentials from an 'AD manager' but it could be any account with sufficient permissions to perform a search on the targeted user entries.

Given that configuration, when the plugin comes to the authorization process, it can properly handle the group membership lookup using the actual user dn.

---

Edit - Despite what the documentation states about `auth_ldap.dn_lookup_bind`

> To do the lookup before binding, set auth_ldap.dn_lookup_bind to a
>   tuple `{UserDN, Password}`.

it may be safer to explicitly set :

```
auth_ldap.dn_lookup_bind.user_dn = <UserDN>
auth_ldap.dn_lookup_bind.password = <Password>
# (OP was required to do so to make it work)
```

Comment: this fixed my problem wonderfully, but I did have to separate dn_lookup_bind into dn_lookup_bind.user_dn and dn_lookup_bind.password.  If i didn't, rabbitmq-server wouldn't start, but I may have been doing something else wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm gonna make an edit to make it clear for others.

Comment: Any idea how can externalize this password to environment variable?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73118279/rabbitmq-how-to-set-and-use-custom-environment-variable-in-rabbitmq-advance-co

Answer (score 2):

Thanks God I have found this answer here :)

If somebody is interested to put this configuration to **advanced RabbitMQ config** file, then it looks like this **(together with `tag queries`)**:

```erlang
[{
  rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap, [
    {dn_lookup_bind, {"CN=someuser,OU=somegroup,OU=othergroup,DC=example,DC=com", "crazypassword"}},
    {tag_queries, [
      {administrator, {in_group, "CN=groupname,OU=somegroup,OU=othergroup,DC=example,DC=com", "member"}},
      {management, {in_group, "CN=groupname,OU=somegroup,OU=othergroup,DC=example,DC=com", "member"}}
    ]}
  ]
}].
```

I couldn't find it anywhere in documentation. **Thanks [EricLavault](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2529954/ericlavault)** for this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56209575/10895880)**

---

**BTW**, I'm using this configuration in **`/etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/rabbitmq.conf`** in Docker cluster:

```erlang
cluster_formation.peer_discovery_backend = rabbit_peer_discovery_classic_config
cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.1 = rabbit@rabbitmq-rabbitmq-1
cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.2 = rabbit@rabbitmq-rabbitmq-2
cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.3 = rabbit@rabbitmq-rabbitmq-3
auth_backends.1 = internal
auth_backends.2 = ldap
auth_ldap.servers.1 = ldap.example.com
auth_ldap.port      = 636
auth_ldap.timeout   = 10000
auth_ldap.idle_timeout = 300000
auth_ldap.use_ssl   = true
auth_ldap.ssl_options.verify = verify_none
auth_ldap.dn_lookup_attribute = sAMAccountName
auth_ldap.dn_lookup_base = DC=example,DC=com
auth_ldap.user_dn_pattern = ${username}
```

Comment: Any idea how can externalize this password to environment variable?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73118279/rabbitmq-how-to-set-and-use-custom-environment-variable-in-rabbitmq-advance-co