# RabbitMQ LDAP on the Management Plugin

Tags: active-directory, ldap, rabbitmq

I am new to RabbitMQ.  I have it installed on Windows 10 Enterpise for development purposes.  We have Active Directory running.  Trying to set up LDAP for the management plugin, so that any user with the right password can login as administrator.

My latest config:

```
[
{
    rabbit,
    [
        {
            auth_backends, [
                {rabbit_auth_backend_ldap, rabbit_auth_backend_internal},
                rabbit_auth_backend_internal
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
  rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap,
  [
    {   
        servers, [
            "WLNC0DS23N.na.mycompany.com","WBRD0DS21N.na.mycompany.com"
        ]
    },
    {
        dn_lookup_attribute, "userPrincipalName"
    },
    {
        dn_lookup_base, "DC=na,DC=mycompany,DC=com"
    },
    {
        user_dn_pattern, "${username}@mycompany.com"
    },
    {
        use_ssl, false
    },
    {
        port, 389
    },          
    {
        log, true
    },
    {
        vhost_access_query, {in_group_nested, "CN=NA_WHS,OU=GroupsAndContacts,OU=Exchange,DC=na,DC=mycompany,DC=com","member"}
    },
    {
        resource_access_query, {in_group_nested, "CN=NA_WHS,OU=GroupsAndContacts,OU=Exchange,DC=na,DC=mycompany,DC=com","member"}
    },
    {
        topic_access_query, {in_group_nested, "CN=NA_WHS,OU=GroupsAndContacts,OU=Exchange,DC=na,DC=mycompany,DC=com","member"}
    },
    {
        tag_queries, [
            {
                administrator, {in_group_nested,"CN=NA_WHS,OU=GroupsAndContacts,OU=Exchange,DC=na,DC=mycompany,DC=com","member"}
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

].

Unfortunately, while LDAP seems to check me out ok, I am not able to login in and get this error in the log:

```
2019-05-28 16:04:14.662 [info] <0.678.0> LDAP CHECK: login for perryda
2019-05-28 16:04:14.663 [info] <0.678.0>         LDAP filling template "${username}@mycompany.com" with
        [{username,<<"perryda">>}]
2019-05-28 16:04:14.663 [info] <0.678.0>         LDAP template result: "perryda@mycompany.com"
2019-05-28 16:04:14.750 [info] <0.317.0>     LDAP bind succeeded: xxxx
2019-05-28 16:04:14.750 [info] <0.317.0>         LDAP filling template "${username}@mycompany.com" with
        [{username,<<"perryda">>}]
2019-05-28 16:04:14.751 [info] <0.317.0>         LDAP template result: "perryda@mycompany.com"
2019-05-28 16:04:14.753 [info] <0.317.0>     LDAP DN lookup: perryda -> CN=Perry\, David,OU=Users,OU=WLNC-Wilmington,OU=OC,OU=IT-SD,DC=na,DC=mycompany,DC=com
2019-05-28 16:04:14.753 [info] <0.317.0>     LDAP CHECK: does perryda have tag administrator?
2019-05-28 16:04:14.753 [info] <0.317.0>     LDAP evaluating query: {in_group_nested,"CN=NA_WHS,OU=GroupsAndContacts,OU=Exchange,DC=na,DC=mycompany,DC=com","member"}
2019-05-28 16:04:14.753 [info] <0.317.0>     LDAP evaluating query: {in_group_nested,"CN=NA_WHS,OU=GroupsAndContacts,OU=Exchange,DC=na,DC=mycompany,DC=com","member",subtree}
2019-05-28 16:04:14.754 [info] <0.317.0>         LDAP filling template "CN=NA_WHS,OU=GroupsAndContacts,OU=Exchange,DC=na,DC=mycompany,DC=com" with
        [{username,<<"perryda">>},{user_dn,"CN=Perry\\, David,OU=Users,OU=WLNC-Wilmington,OU=OC,OU=IT-SD,DC=na,DC=mycompany,DC=com"}]
2019-05-28 16:04:14.754 [info] <0.317.0>         LDAP template result: "CN=NA_WHS,OU=GroupsAndContacts,OU=Exchange,DC=na,DC=mycompany,DC=com"
2019-05-28 16:04:14.759 [info] <0.317.0>     LDAP DECISION: does perryda have tag administrator? true
2019-05-28 16:04:14.759 [info] <0.678.0> LDAP DECISION: login for perryda: ok
2019-05-28 16:04:14.759 [warning] <0.678.0> HTTP access denied: user 'perryda' - invalid credentials
```

Does anyone have a clueon what the problem is, and how to fix?

Comment: By 'instantly logged in' do you mean SSO? Using Kerberos? RabbitMQ does not support this. You can use username/password pairs or X.509 certificates. See https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html#authentication

Comment: It sounds a bit related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56208101/rabbitmq-ldap-authorization-for-groups-with-inconsistent-user-dns. I don't know how works the management plugin but you may have landed into in the same situation: group authorization needs to match user DNs so you need a lookup to occur *before* the authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer was posted by Daniil Fedotov in the RabbitMQ Google Group. It worked great!

Hi,

Your auth backend configuration line "{rabbit_auth_backend_ldap, rabbit_auth_backend_internal}," means that the LDAP backend is used only for authentication (checking that the user exists) but not authorization (checking that the user has access to resources), and internal backend is used for authorization.
This means that you should have permissions and tags configured for the internal user.
If you want authorization to happen via LDAP you should replace this tuple: "{rabbit_auth_backend_ldap, rabbit_auth_backend_internal}" with: "rabbit_auth_backend_ldap".
Or create user permissions in the internal database, but I guess that's not what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

> Trying to set it up so AD users that belong to a particular AD Group
> are just instantly logged in when they access the management plugin
> from IE or Edge.

The management UI doesn't support this. You will have to provide a username and password to log in using AD credentials.

Comment: I see that now and I am just trying to login using my AD user and password.  I am seemingly able to query LDAP correct for group membership, but am still getting an error.  I have updated the question.  Could you please take a look.

Comment: You really should just post to the `rabbitmq-users` list as that is where the core team (including myself) monitors questions. Posting to multiple places just increases confusion. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rabbitmq-users/5hshoFy-QEM/V62Bba9TBAAJ

Comment: Ok - will do that in the future now that I know.

Answer (score 1):

May be it's too late but in my case I've solved my issue with authentication+authorization via LDAP + fallback to internal database with:

```
 {rabbit,
     [
      .......
      {auth_backends, [rabbit_auth_backend_ldap, rabbit_auth_backend_internal]},
      .......
     ]}
```

More details: https://github.com/MarcialRosales/rabbitmq-ldap-integration/blob/master/multiple-auth-backends/README.md