# RabbitMQ LDAP configuration failing on group search

Tags: active-directory, rabbitmq, ldap

I'm trying to set up my the RabbitMQ LDAP provider configuration to be able to authenticate my users and then associate them with the correct user administration tags.

At the moment, rabbitmq seems to be able to authenticate me against AD, but it is then not be able to verify what AD groups I'm in.

Configuration:

```
    ,{rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap, [
                {servers, ["myDC.myDomain.com"]}
                    ,{dn_lookup_bind, {"cn=MyServiceAccount,dc=serviceAccounts,dc=myDomain,dc=com", "Service@ccountPa$$word"}}
                    ,{dn_lookup_attribute, "userPrincipalName"}
                    ,{dn_lookup_base, "DC=myDomain,DC=com"}
                    ,{group_lookup_base, "ou=myLocation,ou=Groups,dc=myDomain,dc=com"}
                    ,{log, true}
                    ,{vhost_access_query, {constant, true}}
                    ,{topic_access_query, {constant, true}}
                    ,{resource_access_query, {constant, true}}
                    ,{tag_queries, [
                        { administrator, { in_group, "CN=rabbitAdmins,OU=myLocation,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com" } },
                        { management, { in_group, "CN=rabbitManagers,OU=myLocation,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com" } }
                    ]}
    ]}
```

Below you can see that it's finding me and it is then unable to resolve my groups.

Some things of note include:

- In the logs where it displays my DN (line 9), it shows an empty array.
- This only seems to work when my username is formatted like myDomain\myUserName

```
2020-01-15 19:22:17.582 [info] <0.2143.0> LDAP CHECK: login for myDomain\myUserName
2020-01-15 19:22:17.582 [info] <0.2143.0>         LDAP filling template "${username}" with
            [{username,<<"myDomain\\myUserName">>},{ad_domain,<<"myDomain">>},{ad_user,<<"myUserName">>}]
2020-01-15 19:22:17.582 [info] <0.2143.0>         LDAP template result: "myDomain\myUserName"
2020-01-15 19:22:17.589 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP bind succeeded: xxxx
2020-01-15 19:22:17.589 [info] <0.367.0>         LDAP filling template "${username}" with
            [{username,<<"myDomain\\myUserName">>},{ad_domain,<<"myDomain">>},{ad_user,<<"myUserName">>}]
2020-01-15 19:22:17.589 [info] <0.367.0>         LDAP template result: "myDomain\myUserName"
2020-01-15 19:22:17.591 [warning] <0.367.0> Searching for DN for myDomain\myUserName, got back []
2020-01-15 19:22:17.594 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP bind succeeded: CN=xxxx,OU=xxxx,DC=xxxx,DC=xxxx
2020-01-15 19:22:17.594 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP CHECK: does myDomain\myUserName have tag administrator?
2020-01-15 19:22:17.594 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP evaluating query: {in_group,"CN=rabbitAdmins,OU=myLocation,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com"}
2020-01-15 19:22:17.594 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP evaluating query: {in_group,"CN=rabbitAdmins,OU=myLocation,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com","member"}
2020-01-15 19:22:17.594 [info] <0.367.0>         LDAP filling template "CN=rabbitAdmins,OU=myLocation,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com" with
            [{username,<<"myDomain\\myUserName">>},{user_dn,"myDomain\\myUserName"},{ad_domain,<<"myDomain">>},{ad_user,<<"myUserName">>}]
2020-01-15 19:22:17.594 [info] <0.367.0>         LDAP template result: "CN=rabbitAdmins,OU=myLocation,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com"
2020-01-15 19:22:17.596 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP evaluated in_group for "CN=rabbitAdmins,OU=myLocation,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com": false
2020-01-15 19:22:17.596 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP DECISION: does myDomain\myUserName have tag administrator? false
2020-01-15 19:22:17.596 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP CHECK: does myDomain\myUserName have tag management?
2020-01-15 19:22:17.596 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP evaluating query: {in_group,"CN=rabbitManagers,OU=myLocation,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com"}
2020-01-15 19:22:17.596 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP evaluating query: {in_group,"CN=rabbitManagers,OU=myLocation,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com","member"}
2020-01-15 19:22:17.596 [info] <0.367.0>         LDAP filling template "CN=rabbitManagers,OU=myLocation,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com" with
            [{username,<<"myDomain\\myUserName">>},{user_dn,"myDomain\\myUserName"},{ad_domain,<<"myDomain">>},{ad_user,<<"myUserName">>}]
2020-01-15 19:22:17.596 [info] <0.367.0>         LDAP template result: "CN=rabbitManagers,OU=myLocation,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com"
2020-01-15 19:22:17.597 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP evaluated in_group for "CN=rabbitManagers,OU=myLocation,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com": false
2020-01-15 19:22:17.598 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP DECISION: does myDomain\myUserName have tag management? false
2020-01-15 19:22:17.598 [info] <0.2143.0> LDAP DECISION: login for myDomain\myUserName: ok
2020-01-15 19:22:17.598 [warning] <0.2143.0> HTTP access denied: user 'myDomain\myUserName' - Not management user
```

On another post I read that they got theirs to work by setting the user_dn_pattern and also changing the dn_lookup_attribute to "distinguishedName" instead. This seems to work for me, but unfortunately my company's DNs aren't standardized, so if I did that, I could only get a small subset of my users to work.

Configuration:

```
    ,{rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap, [
                {servers, ["myDC.myDomain.com"]}
                    ,{dn_lookup_bind, {"CN=myServiceAccount,OU=Services,DC=myDomain,DC=com", "Service@ccountPa$$word"}}
                    ,{dn_lookup_attribute, "distinguishedName"}
                    ,{user_dn_pattern, "CN=${username},OU=randomSubOU,OU=Developers,OU=Users,OU=myLocation,DC=myDomain,DC=com"}
                    ,{dn_lookup_base, "DC=myDomain,DC=com"}
                    ,{group_lookup_base, "ou=myLocation,ou=Groups,dc=myDomain,dc=com"}
                    ,{log, true}
                    ,{vhost_access_query, {constant, true}}
                    ,{topic_access_query, {constant, true}}
                    ,{resource_access_query, {constant, true}}
                    ,{tag_queries, [
                        { administrator, { in_group, "CN=rabbitAdmins,OU=myLocation,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com" } },
                        { management, { in_group, "CN=rabbitManagers,OU=myLocation,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com" } }
                    ]}
    ]}
```

In the logs you can see that it's finding me and then associating me with the correct groups, but it won't work for users whose DNs does not match my DN exactly

Some things of note include:

- I don't have to specify my domain in this configuration

My DN: *CN=myUserName,OU=randomSubOU,OU=Developers,OU=Users,OU=myLocation,DC=myDomain,DC=com*

```
2020-01-15 21:19:15.795 [info] <0.3040.0> LDAP CHECK: login for myUserName
2020-01-15 21:19:15.804 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP bind succeeded: CN=xxxx,OU=xxxx,DC=xxxx,DC=xxxx
2020-01-15 21:19:15.804 [info] <0.367.0>         LDAP filling template "CN=${username},OU=randomSubOU,OU=Developers,OU=Users,OU=myLocation,DC=myDomain,DC=com" with
            [{username,<<"myUserName">>}]
2020-01-15 21:19:15.804 [info] <0.367.0>         LDAP template result: "CN=myUserName,OU=randomSubOU,OU=Developers,OU=Users,OU=myLocation,DC=myDomain,DC=com"
2020-01-15 21:19:15.812 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP DN lookup: myUserName -> CN=myUserName,OU=randomSubOU,OU=Developers,OU=Users,OU=myLocation,DC=myDomain,DC=com
2020-01-15 21:19:15.825 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP bind succeeded: CN=xxxx,OU=xxxx,OU=xxxx,OU=xxxx,OU=xxxx,DC=xxxx,DC=xxxx
2020-01-15 21:19:15.825 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP CHECK: does myUserName have tag administrator?
2020-01-15 21:19:15.825 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP evaluating query: {in_group,"CN=rabbitAdmins,OU=myLocation,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com"}
2020-01-15 21:19:15.825 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP evaluating query: {in_group,"CN=rabbitAdmins,OU=myLocation,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com","member"}
2020-01-15 21:19:15.825 [info] <0.367.0>         LDAP filling template "CN=rabbitAdmins,OU=myLocation,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com" with
            [{username,<<"myUserName">>},{user_dn,"CN=myUserName,OU=randomSubOU,OU=Developers,OU=Users,OU=myLocation,DC=myDomain,DC=com"}]
2020-01-15 21:19:15.825 [info] <0.367.0>         LDAP template result: "CN=rabbitAdmins,OU=myLocation,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com"
2020-01-15 21:19:15.833 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP evaluated in_group for "CN=rabbitAdmins,OU=myLocation,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com": true
2020-01-15 21:19:15.834 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP DECISION: does myUserName have tag administrator? true
2020-01-15 21:19:15.834 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP CHECK: does myUserName have tag management?
2020-01-15 21:19:15.834 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP evaluating query: {in_group,"CN=rabbitManagers,OU=myLocation,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com"}
2020-01-15 21:19:15.834 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP evaluating query: {in_group,"CN=rabbitManagers,OU=myLocation,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com","member"}
2020-01-15 21:19:15.834 [info] <0.367.0>         LDAP filling template "CN=rabbitManagers,OU=myLocation,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com" with
            [{username,<<"myUserName">>},{user_dn,"CN=myUserName,OU=randomSubOU,OU=Developers,OU=Users,OU=myLocation,DC=myDomain,DC=com"}]
2020-01-15 21:19:15.834 [info] <0.367.0>         LDAP template result: "CN=rabbitManagers,OU=myLocation,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com"
2020-01-15 21:19:15.842 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP evaluated in_group for "CN=rabbitManagers,OU=myLocation,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com": true
2020-01-15 21:19:15.843 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP DECISION: does myUserName have tag management? true
```

and here is what that logs look like when one of my peers (From a different OU) logs in

My Peer's DN: *CN=myPeer,OU=Developers,OU=Users,OU=myLocation,DC=myDomain,DC=com*

```
2020-01-15 21:23:30.760 [info] <0.3394.0> LDAP CHECK: login for myPeer
2020-01-15 21:23:30.764 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP bind succeeded: CN=xxxx,OU=xxxx,DC=xxxx,DC=xxxx
2020-01-15 21:23:30.765 [info] <0.367.0>         LDAP filling template "CN=${username},OU=randomSubOU,OU=Developers,OU=Users,OU=myLocation,DC=myDomain,DC=com" with
            [{username,<<"myPeer">>}]
2020-01-15 21:23:30.765 [info] <0.367.0>         LDAP template result: "CN=myPeer,OU=randomSubOU,OU=Developers,OU=Users,OU=myLocation,DC=myDomain,DC=com"
2020-01-15 21:23:30.766 [warning] <0.367.0> Searching for DN for CN=myPeer,OU=randomSubOU,OU=Developers,OU=Users,OU=myLocation,DC=myDomain,DC=com, got back []
2020-01-15 21:23:30.768 [info] <0.367.0>     LDAP bind returned "invalid credentials": CN=xxxx,OU=xxxx,OU=xxxx,OU=xxxx,OU=xxxx,DC=xxxx,DC=xxxx
2020-01-15 21:23:30.768 [info] <0.3394.0> LDAP DECISION: login for myPeer: denied
2020-01-15 21:23:30.768 [warning] <0.3394.0> HTTP access denied: CN=myPeer,OU=randomSubOU,OU=Developers,OU=Users,OU=myLocation,DC=myDomain,DC=com
```

Comment: Try with `dn_lookup_attribute = sAMAccountName` and try to set the tuple {binddn,password} as described in this (duplicate?) [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56209575/2529954).

Answer (score 2):

I ended up figuring this out. Like Eric had mentioned, it looks like I needed to switch dn_lookup_attribute to sAMAccountName name.

```
,{rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap, [
            {servers, ["myDC.myDomain.com"]}
                ,{dn_lookup_bind, {"CN=MyServiceAccount,OU=Services,DC=myDomain,DC=com", "Service@ccountPa$$word"}}
                ,{dn_lookup_attribute, "sAMAccountName"}
                ,{dn_lookup_base, "DC=myDomain,DC=com"}
                ,{group_lookup_base, "ou=myLocation,ou=Groups,dc=myDomain,dc=com"}
                ,{log, true}
                ,{vhost_access_query, {constant, true}}
                ,{topic_access_query, {constant, true}}
                ,{resource_access_query, {constant, true}}
                ,{tag_queries, [
                    { administrator, { in_group, "CN=rabbitAdmins,OU=myLocation,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com" } },
                    { management, { in_group, "CN=rabbitManagers,OU=myLocation,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com" } },
                ]}
]}
```