# RabbitMQ : How to set and use custom environment variable in RabbitMQ Advance config file

Tags: rabbitmq, ldap

We have configured RabbitMQ server to communicate with LDAP server for  authentication **which is working as expected**. But we are facing one challenge where we need to externalize one value from configuration to environment variable.

so below is the current configuration present in `advance.config` file

```
{other_bind, {"CN=Service_Account,OU=Service Accounts,DC=XYZ,DC=com",{string,"123456"}}},
```

and want to make it something like this

```
{other_bind, {"CN=Service_Account,OU=Service Accounts,DC=XYZ,DC=com",{string,"${RABBITMQ_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD}"}}},
```

so as a result we wanted to externalize our password to some environment variable and use the same in `advance.config` file.

I tried setting value in rabbitmq-env.conf file but no luck.

Also as per this article we can't set a custom environment variable in `rabbitmq-env.conf` file, is it right? and if yes then where we can set this value?

https://riptutorial.com/rabbitmq/example/14032/configuring-rabbitmq-on--nix-systems

Comment: Can I ask why you need to "externalize" the password ? Having it in rabbitmq-env.conf rather than in another config file boils down to pretty much the same thing.

Comment: The complete list of "supported" environment variables is [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#supported-environment-variables). I don't know if they can be used in the advanced config file or if you can add custom ones. First I would check if `rabbitmq-env.conf` is correctly taken into account by setting one of the listed variables to an arbitrary value and see if it's reflected in the config, and then check if that same variable can be used (expanded) in `advanced.config`. Then I would try with a custom variable, knowing that it might not be automatically prefixed by "RABBITMQ_"...

Comment: Thanks EricLavault, We wanted to fetch this service account password from CyberArc and put it inside the env file at the time of bootup and later using the same in advance.conf file, that was the plan.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not supported:

```
{other_bind, {"CN=Service_Account,OU=Service Accounts,DC=XYZ,DC=com",{string,"${RABBITMQ_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD}"}}},
```

One option is to generate the `advanced.config` from a template before RabbitMQ starts. If RabbitMQ starts via `systemd` in your environment, you can use the [`ExecStartPre`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) hook to run a custom script or program.

To create a drop-in override for the RabbitMQ `systemd` unit (and add `ExecStartPre`), follow these instructions:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd#Editing_provided_units